# registration of new users with Devise and omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, google-oauth

I've trying to manage user sign up with google account for my rails 4.0.0 app. Devise works perfectly. And there is working sign in with Google Account for existing users. But I have some difficulties with new user registration using Google Oauth 2. For example: i've got google account "example@google.com". It's logged in on my current PC. And when I try to sign up with this account to my app it generates blank register form. If I dont manually provide email, login, full name, etc. - I've got error message that they "cannot be blank". I guess solution is create default value to text fields to fetch user details. 
So, my question is how can I provide values for variables in view that equals variables from google account?

Email field in form_for in new user registration:

```
= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :value => 'how can i put auth.info.email here?'
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in Through Google!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      flash.notice = "You are almost Done! Please provide a password to finish setting up your account"
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

omniauth method from user model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    if user = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email)
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user
    else
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.full_name = auth.info.name
        user.email = auth.info.email # THIS (user.email) value i want to provide to my registration form as default value
        user.birthday = auth.info.birthday
        user.avatar = auth.info.image
     end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Show your omniauth configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with GitHub you can take a look at my user model

https://github.com/flower-pot/pastebin/blob/master/app/models/user.rb